# Restart Tomcat6 Wepapp using Curl?

Tags: curl, tomcat6

I am trying to reload a Tomcat6 web application (for example the Tomcat Documentation) via Curl.

I have tried it with:

```
curl.exe --user username:password http://myserver:8080/manager/list/stop?path=/docs
```

This doesn't work (Error 404).

I recorded the request with live HTTP headers. If I use the replay functionality it *does* work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo. Change `manager/list/stop` to `manager/stop` in the url.

```
curl.exe --user user:pass http://myserver:8080/manager/text/stop?path=/docs
```

It stops the application. If you want to restart you need the `reload` parameter:

```
curl.exe --user user:pass http://myserver:8080/manager/reload?path=/docs
```

Note: Tomcat 7 uses different management urls.

References:

- [Manager App HOW-TO, Tomcat 6.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html)
- [Manager App HOW-TO, Tomcat 7.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

Comment: thx for your answer but i still get an Error saying that the requested resource is not available. Btw, how do u know its /text instead of /list? Ok i found the solution, stupid me: its curl.exe --user user:password http://myserver:8080/manager/stop?path=/docs!

Comment: Sorry, I only linked the documentation in [your other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/323688/restart-a-single-tomcat-7-webapp-at-a-specific-time), not here. Check the update, please.

Comment: I've just realized that Tomcat 6 uses different urls than Tomcat 7. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this on command line,

Create a file for tomcat-users.xml inside CATALINA_HOME/conf as this example.

**Example**

Allow the tomcat for manager-text role.

```
<user password="Password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-text" username="admin"/>

curl --user admin:Password http://{ip}:{Port}/manager/**text**/reload?path=/Context
```

Output:

```
OK - Reloaded application at context path /examples
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a this config to your conf/tomcat-users.txt

```
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin,manager"/>
<user username="user-reload" password="passowrd" roles="manager-script"/>
```

You need to run curl:

```
curl --user user-reload:password http://mytomcat.local:8080/manager/reload?path=/docs
OK - Reloaded application at context path /docs
```